# SignalR and Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, signalr

Does anybody have SignalR and Sitecore working together?

There is an issue in Sitecore with hitting the 
Application_Start in Sitecore and getting it to kickoff RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs().

I have double checked that I am mapping to my URL/signalR/hubs default on the layouts.
The script blocks for JQuery, JQuery SignalR, and the custom JS are also included.

It pulls everything down fine on the Client Side, except that the URL/signalr/hubs is not mapping.

I have noticed some special handling needed in Sitecore for MVC RouteTables, but these do not directly address the issue currently experienced.

Thanks -

Comment: What version of Sitecore?

Comment: It is 6.6 (as Kevin correctly assumed) Update 3.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after so working on this for a bit...

It was the simple thing that makes this work.

You have to add the /signalr and /signalr/hubs to the Ignore Path for SignalR to work with Sitecore.

```
<setting name="IgnoreUrlPrefixes"                value="/sitecore/default.aspx|/trace.axd|.....|/signalr|/signalr/hubs" />
```

After I got that into place, I was able to see the MapHubs wire up correctly in the Application_Start.  It would not consistently hit the break point before since it couldn't provide the URL without trying to get a Sitecore item.  Now I see it hit the breakpoint consistently.

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you are using Sitecore 6.6 as you've mentioned the Sitecore MVC RouteTables. Try using [WebActivator](https://github.com/davidebbo/WebActivator) to register your hub mappings in the RouteTable. WebActivator gives you options to add this bootstrap code into either a `PreApplicationStartMethod` or a `PostApplicationStartMethod` so that you can register your routes and avoid Sitecore's wildcard route taking precedence. I have used this approach to bootstrap Web API routes under Sitecore.

```
using System;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(
    typeof($rootnamespace$.App_Start.MySuperPackage), "PreStart")]

namespace $rootnamespace$.App_Start {
    public static class MySuperPackage {
        public static void PreStart() {
            // Add your start logic here
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative approach would be to add the registration code into a custom pipeline processor and add this processor into the initialize event pipeline in `App_Config\Include\Sitecore.Mvc.config`

```
<pipelines>

  <!-- Loader -->

  <initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeGlobalFilters, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeControllerFactory, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc"/>
  </initialize>
```

Comment: Interested to hear what you end up with as I'm looking at some Sitecore and SignalR work shortly.

Comment: Kevin - see below.  WHat got me stuck, was that when you check your URL/signalR/hubs directory, Sitecore would do the Item Not Found behavior AND the Application_Start was getting hit (about half the time).

So to be clear, you do not need to enable MVC nor do any pre-processor handling to get it the MapHubs hit in your Sitecore.Web.Application, (we use this as a replacement for the Globalasax.cs for the Global.asax as best practice).  You only have to add the path into the IgnoreUrlPrefixes.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, shall try it out next week.